# Why does my conditional display of 2D array elements fail?

Tags: jstl

I have a 2-dimensional array, which can be done like this (working code):

```
 <c:forEach items="${dataArray}" var="row">     
    Subject id: ${row[0]}    
 </c:forEach>
```

But I want to add a condition; when I try this it does not display anything:

```
 <c:forEach items="${dataArray}" var="row">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(${row[0]}, 'condtion1')}">
            Subject id: ${row[0]}
        </c:when>
    </c:choose>
 </c:forEach>
```

Have I got something wring in the `test` attribute that makes it always false?

Comment: What is the problem? What is the expected output, and what is the actual output?

Comment: The test statement <c:when test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(${row[0]}, 'condtion1')}"> caused nothing to be displayed.  My colleague  has figured out that it should be: <c:when test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(row[0], 'condtion1')}">

Comment: Edited to make clearer what the symptom is.

Comment: Did you spell `condtion1` consistently throughout?  And not as `condition1`, perhaps?  Without seeing some sample rows it's impossible to answer this question.  Please [edit] to show some test input.